# How to increase the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

1) how to increase the intensity without increasing the Frequency? if possible

2) how to increase the number of photons emitted per second per atom-electron ? is there a limit..

> [Electromagnetic radiation is characterized by a broad range of wavelengths and frequencies, each associated with a specific intensity (or amplitude) and quantity of energy.](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/wavebasics/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  But a laser does what you seem to be asking.

Comment: Laser uses many atoms to increase the amplitude which is the opposite of my second question.

Comment: Lasers have many atoms, but one atom increases the field amplitude by the equivalent of one photon.  You can increase the number of photons emitted per second by increasing the rate at which the atoms are re-energized.

Comment: @garyp diffidently but i will not know if I didn't ask the question, so I am sure why it's on hold ?

Answer (score 2):

1) It's difficult to combine the wave and particle view of photons. Many photons super-imposed constitute a higher amplitude EM wave. Photon energy is quantised and dependent on frequency only.

In the EM wave view the wave energy/unit area is related to the square of E field amplitude.

But if you try to apply that to an individual photon what area is relevant?

> [You could say the cross sectional area represents the “size” of a photon, but the problem with this is that a photon’s cross section varies depending on what it is interacting with. Photons interact pretty strongly with electrons, and have a relatively large cross section, but with neutrons the interaction is smaller. Under this definition there is no absolute “size” to a photon. The cross section also depends upon the energy of the photon and things like its polarization. There are also different cross sections for absorption vs scattering.](https://briankoberlein.com/2015/04/14/thats-about-the-size-of-it/)

For an "individual photon" of a given frequency and therefore given energy (fixed by quantisation and plank's constant) the corresponding E field amplitude must also be fixed.

$$A_e=\sqrt{2Ec\mu_0}$$

A is amplitude
E is energy $E=h\nu$
$\mu_0$ is free space permeability
c is speed of light

(more [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html))

Perhaps someone will sort this out, don't take it from me as definitive.

2) Increase the emission rate by stimulating the emitting particles with more energy - yet avoid temperature dependent color changes that come from black body radiation. Either allow thermal equilibrium to be achieved or try a Laser in which the cascaded emission energy is fixed.

Comment: by "photons super-imposed" do yo mean: "binding two photons together so that one would sit right atop the other, superimposed as they travel"

Comment: Well there is no binding, but otherwise yes, it is interference.

Comment: In the above expressions it is the same for each frequency.

Comment: This is saying that when the rate of energy transfer per unit area gets to the magnitude of an individual photon energy, then QM kicks in, it won't drop lower. Instead the probability of interaction with that single remaining photon drops off.

Comment: No *each* frequency has. Question has been put on hold, I think most readers want it to be clearer - I can't see those votes though.